# How to make a reset button in excel

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am trying to make a **reset button** that will replace any value the user has selected with the value `TOTAL` inside a number of comboboxes. Using the record macro i selected the combobox but i can't figure out how to insert the value. The following code gives out the 424 error.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ComboBox2")).Select.Value = TOTAL
```

the part that i added to the macro is the `.Value=TOTAL`

Anyone knows what i should do? Please take note that i don't want to clear the comboboxes; I want to give them a specific value.

Comment: Do you have a *linked cell*? If you change the value of the linked cell to the index number of the *TOTAL* value, doesn't the combobox change appropriately?

Comment: Do you want to add the string `TOTAL` to the `combobox` list? 
Also try it with `.Text` or just `.Value` instead of `.Select.Value`

Comment: no,i don't think there is any kind of link with the cells on the sheet,in the end the cells behind the combobox displayed the value

Comment: no,the value TOTAL already exists in the list,i am trying to make a button that will reset every combobox there is to the TOTAL value

Answer (score 0):

- In case that combo boxes are **Form controls** use `OLEFormat.Object.ListIndex` to select the item.
- In case that the combo boxes are **ActiveX controls** use `OLEFormat.Object.Object.ListIndex` *(note in this case the first item in the list has index 0).*

Then iterate through all Combo-boxes you want to reset and set `ListIndex` to index of item `"TOTAL"`. In this example the item `"TOTAL"` is on the first place in the list so for Form Combo-box (if used) `ListIndex = 1` and for ActiveX Combo-box `ListIndex = 0`. HTH

*(You are probably using ActiveX Combo-boxes, but in the example the older Form Combo-boxes are used as well just for the case).*

```
Sub ResetToTotal2()
    Dim combos
    Dim combo
    Dim comboObject

    combos = Array("ComboBox1", "ComboBox2", "ComboBox3")

    For Each combo In combos
        Set comboObject = ActiveSheet.Shapes(combo).OLEFormat.Object
        If TypeName(comboObject) = "DropDown" Then
            comboObject.ListIndex = 1
        Else
            comboObject.Object.ListIndex = 0
        End If
    Next combo
End Sub
```

Comment: Using your solution i still got an error on the ActiveSheet line (n 438).I tried the following  <br/>   'Sub ResetToTotal()
    Dim combos()
    Dim combo

    combos = Array("ComboBox1", "ComboBox2", "ComboBox3", "ComboBox4", "ComboBox5", "ComboBox6", "ComboBox7", "ComboBox8", "ComboBox9")
    For Each combo In combos
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(combo).OLEFormat.Object.ListFillRange = "TOTAL"
    Next combo
End Sub'   <br/>  and although it produces no error,it also does nothing

Comment: i also cant write it down correctly for you to see,sorry.  Sub ResetToTotal() Dim combos() Dim combo combos = Array("ComboBox1", "ComboBox2", "ComboBox3", "ComboBox4", "ComboBox5", "ComboBox6", "ComboBox7", "ComboBox8", "ComboBox9") For Each combo In combos ActiveSheet.Shapes(combo).OLEFormat.Object.ListFillRange = "TOTAL" Next combo End Sub

Comment: Hmmm hmmm hmmm ... well if you still need solution for this, could you prepare example excel workbook with at least one combo box and its data and properties how you are using it. Upload it e.g. to Drop-Box? This workbook should contain the VBA code whit the function ResetToTotal2 and please mark the line where error occured (it is probably here comboObject.Object.ListIndex = 0). And thanks, happy new year to you as well :-)